# What to do on an audit in the Triage review that looks like spam but is not really spam?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, triage, spam

I came across this [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/10353067) in the Triage review:

[image]

From the start I knew it was an audit. No problem there. I am however torn into what to do. Looking at the question it does not seem to be spam. Normally spam contain text like

> Try these new product! Call us now [some phone number here]! Try these new product! ...

The link in the question seems to be legit(it goes to www.gmailhelpsomething.com). I did not click it though.

No doubt that this question should be closed. So I flagged it as Unsalvageable > Off Topic > Blatantly not about programming. I passed the audit so no problem there either.

My problem is that *what if* that was not an audit but a legitimate review/post. I [understand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work) that spam flags should be used sparingly. What should I have done?

Comment: It lists an arbitrary phone number and links to an arbitrary site (which is almost certainly *not* Google's actual support site), and alleges those to be some awesome thing. How is this not spam?

Comment: @NathanTuggy That's what I'm not sure of that's why I thought of bringing this to meta. In the review, I did **not** flag it as spam, but I still passed the audit. That's why I thought maybe it's not spam. I'm not really sure here because review audits are supposed to be easy i.e. clear cut and not confusing.

Comment: Well, audits are more forgiving; as long as you take a clearly negative action toward known-bad, and a clearly positive toward known-good, you're fine... even if that means downvoting spam in Late Answers.

Comment: When I got to it in the review, my first impression is that it is spam. Upon reading it, it does not seem to be spam. So to confirm my suspicions, I purposely flagged it differently expecting that I will fail the audit. But I did not so that got me very confused.

Comment: For future reference: the *only* known-bad audits in Triage are spam.

Comment: @NathanTuggy your response came in at the same time as my comment lol. As per your comment, well that makes sense.

Comment: @NathanTuggy again, same time as my comment. Anyway, I did not know that the only known-bad audits in Triage are spam. Now that I know that, I think won't be confused in the future(I hope).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is absolutely clearly spam.

Because:

- The text makes no real sense
- not a link to a google website
- arbitrary phone number
- generally not even a question

So yes, it is spam. You should have flagged it as spam. Closing or deleting is also fine (as the Audit acknowledged). If you have questions wether or not something is spam, ask yourself:

- Does this make any sense?
- Are phone numbers and/or links posted anything but noise?
- Are there product links to paid for products in there?
- Is it tacitly (or indirectly) promoting a service?

If your answer to some of the above is yes, its probably spam.

Comment: Thanks for the checklist. Will keep it in mind next time.